# AngularJS pass directive to direcive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a very common pattern that occurs, simplified it is along the lines of (pretend the all caps things are directives)

```
SOMESTUFF
BUTTONS
HEADER
<div ng-repeat="blah in data">
    CONTENT
</div>
FOOTER
```

This is the same and repeated throughout the app, and will be repeated in subsequent apps. However, occasionally (particularly in the future) we will have a few pages where BUTTONS will be different but everything else the same. Or maybe CONTENT is different. Obviously, I could make each of these sections a directive and on each page put something like the above, however if I decide there needs to be MORESTUFF after FOOTER on every page I have to go through every page and add this.

Therefore, I feel the ideal setup would be one big directive, that contains each of the above smaller directives, and then be able to plug in other directives, so something along the lines of:

```
<BIGDIRECTIVE header="SPECIALHEADER">
```

And that would generate a big directive but with SPECIALHEADER in place of HEADER. Equally I could do

```
<BIGDIRECTIVE header="SPECIALHEADER" footer="SPECIALFOOTER">
```

Is this a good idea, or even possible? Does something like this exist or would I have to generate and compile the sub-directives on the fly?